# YUM not working in CENTOS 7 after installing httpd

Tags: linux, python, yum, centos7

I just installed CENTOS 7 on my vmware.
After YUM update everything worked fine for sometime then system suddenly crashed and asked me to Logout.

In console in tried to `yum update` but it showed following error:

> There was problem importing one of the Python modules required to run
>   yum. The error leading to this problem was:

```
/lib64/libxml2.so.2:File too short
```

> Please install a package which provides this module or verify that
>   module is installed correctly
>
> Its possible that the above module does not match the current version
>   of Python, which is 2.7.5 (default, Sept 2016, 22:37:46)  [GCC 4.8.5
>   2015(Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589971/yum-not-working) but, did not work for me.
I just know basic of Linux OS so please help me fix this issue.

I get the following error :
[image: Error on YUM Update]

[image: DF command]

Comment: type df to check full filesystems

Comment: @bgtvfr i have added a screenshot of what i get

Answer (score 1):

Download libxml2 to your system:

```
wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.9.2009/updates/x86_64/Packages/libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7.5.x86_64.rpm
```

Re-install the libxml2 package with RPM

```
rpm -Uvh --force libxml2-2.9.1-6.el7.5.x86_64.rpm
```

Finally, attempt to reinstall the package (to ensure correct versioning) using yum.

```
yum reinstall libxml2
```

If you continue to receive errors it would seem as though there has been some underlying filesystem corruption or the underlying block device in the virtual machine is thin provisioned without enough actual filesystem space on the hypervisor to support that much space.

Comment: I cant install as i am disconnected from network due to this crash, i am installing fresh install, is there anything i should take care of from now on ?

Comment: Cant tell, since the cause is still not known. I would check your hypervisor has enough disk space for the amount of disk you are creating in the VM.

Comment: That can be the reason, as i increased the RAM for my VM and the crash occurred